# Назначение cookies Express.js

Tags: node.js, cookie, mongodb, express, mongoose

Хочу сделать вход в аккаунт. Ввожу логин и пароль, после чего в пост запросе производится запрос к БД с соответствующим логином, если мы нашли такой логин, то сопоставляем пароли, если совпали, то если была нажата галочка "Запомнить", назначаем куки. Я их назначаю внутри асинхронной функции (как я понял). После чего хочу перейти на эту страничку. Вот тут и возникает проблема. Иногда переходит на ту страничку, а иногда не переходит (чаще просто страничка показывает, что загружается, но так и остается "висеть"). В случаях, когда "везет", и иногда переходит на страничку, через `console.log()` назначенные куки определяет как `undefined`, хотя в браузере эти куки сохранены (в настройках посмотрел). Как решить данную проблему, чтобы и переходило корректно на страницу, и куки определяло.

Это запрос, на котором ищется пользователь:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

    //функция, которая возвращает состояние запроса
    function getPromiseOfQueryForUser(objModel,infoForSearch){
        var promise = objModel.findOne({login :infoForSearch}).exec();
        return promise;
    }

    var Users = models.Users;

    //состояние логина
    var promiseLogin = getPromiseOfQueryForUser(Users,req.body.login);

    promiseLogin.then(function(user){
        if ( user.password == req.body.password ){
            if (req.body.rememberSignIn) {//если нажата галочка 'Запомнить'
            //назначить куки
                var minute = 10 * 1000;
                res.cookie('user',  { login:user.login,
                                      password:user.password},
                                    { maxAge: minute,
                                      httpOnly:true});
                console.log("Cookies is set!");
            }

            return res.redirect('/user/'+user.login);
        } else {
           return res.redirect("/signin");
        }
    }, function(err){   //произошла ошибка при анализе состояния
        console.log(err);
        return  res.redirect("/signin");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По части cookies. У Вас стоит `httpOnly:true`, что запрещает на клиенте, изнутри js обращаться к ним. Если необходимо иметь такую возможность - необходимо изменять на `false`.

По части подвисания - Вы уверены, что запрос в БД выполнился успешно? Если нет, точно ли при ошибке происходит `reject` промиса? (в конкретно представленном коде - больше не вижу с ходу причин вот так подвиснуть, `return` завершает каждую ветку).

**Не храните пароль пользователя в открытом виде (погуглите на тему bcrypt и подобных ему вещей). И тем более не сохраняйте его в кукису.**

---

**Upd:** Кстати, возможно, что редирект происходит, а вот страничка, на которую Вы пытаетесь попасть, просто не отдается (не отправляет содержимое или даже заголовки), тогда вы можете получить вот такое подвисание.

Comment: Спасибо за совет про пароль, да, я уверен на счет того, что запрос проходит успешно, опять тем же самым console.log()

Comment: Я попробовал сделать false, все равно - пишется соединение в title и ничего не происходит, так и висит в режиме соединения, в консоли доходит до строки "Cookies are set"

Comment: попробую пока посмотреть доку к express.js, может есть тонкость какая, попробуйте пока-что перед `return res.redirect('/user/'+user.login);` но после условия `if` вставить логирование чего-нить.

Comment: Прологировал, все выводиться. Заметил закономерность, если вместо  'return res.redirect('/user/'+user.login)' вставить 'return res.send('/user/'+user.login)', то выводится строка user/MyFirstUser (в зависимости, конечно, от логина, информация меняется)

Comment: ну значит дело в конечной страничке (см. Upd ответа)

Comment: Не могли бы пояснить? Если я эту страничку просто попытаюсь вызвать через адресную строку, то мне ее выводит без проблем.

Comment: хм, ну вообще, предположение было в том, что как раз страничка по адресу `/user/чего_то_там`, тупит с отдачей контента (возможно при наличии кук, возможно без них), вот и происходит подвисание. Но если он в обоих случаях ее выводит и так... не знаю даже, что там происходить может. В целом можно открыть инструменты разработчика, вкладку веб-запросов, включить непрерывное логирование и посмотреть, что там происходит.

кстати, проверьте, что страничка `/signin` тоже корректно отдается (на всякий случай)

Comment: /signin корректоно отдается. Еще одна странность, если я не ставлю галочку "Запомнить", то переход на страницу вот именно через этот res.redirect проходит, иначе, висит (зашел в эту вкладку разработчка, GET - запрос на эту страничку красным горит).

Comment: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/9ZVA/xYoMMbzM9 - скриншот

Comment: ну тут однозначно вариант с неправильным редиректом отпадает (Вы уже ушли на GET), проверьте, что в случае наличиствующей кукисы, вы не уходите по ветке исполнения в тупик без `return next()` или `return res.send()`. 1. Если Вы используете несколкьо функций обработчиков, возможно, какая-то из них  не вызывает `next()`, тогда будут именно эти симптомы. 2. Если в ответе в случае отстуствия кукисы вы делаете `res.send()`, а в при наличии - нет, эффект тот же.

Comment: скрин лучше уберите, а то там пароль видно) хотя... явно тестовый=)

Comment: Конечно тестовый пароль:) А по делу, как я понял, у меня с п.1 и 2 все в порядке, в get запросе 'router.get('/:login', function(req, res, next)' у меня первой строкой console.log стоит, он не выводиться

Comment: АААА!!! Заработало! Я все-таки решил более тщательно проверить свои use, и я нашел именно то, что вы писали в пункте 1. Спасибо огромное!